# DVC remove unused file from remote repository S3

Tags: version-control, dvc, remote-repository

I'm trying to remove 1 file from S3 remote repository which is no longer tracked by DVC.

So, I did:

- dvc remove .dvc file
- git add & commit the .gitignore and .dvc files
- run `dvc gc -c --workspace`

however, the process of deleting 1 file (13KB) took 6 minutes, is that normal or is there a step I'm missing?

here's the details for `dvc gc -c --workspace`:

[delete process img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQWme.png)

[delete process img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBzrc.png)

reference: https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/gc

Comment: Git itself doesn't take part in the dvc operations here. Updating the .dvc file is of course important, and Git is storing the .dvc file in commits, but all the subsequent work happens outside of Git.

Answer (score 0):

From the `dvc gc` [documentation](https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/gc#-w):

```
-w, --workspace - keep only files and directories referenced in the workspace. 
This option is enabled automatically with the other scope options (below).
```

It means that this command removes all the files *except* those that are still in use (referenced) in the workspace and *only* in the workspace.

In your case this command would remove data that belongs to the previous commits in the repo. This might be taking time.